How to get Angles using Dot Product
In the below link , I have a picture with two 3d Models numbered 1 and 2 . I am trying to figure out the angle between the Base of the Part and the Side Flange(face) of the Part. As inputs, I have Vector A which runs along the length of the Part and Vector B which is normal to the Side face of the model. Given these two inputs I am trying to get the angles between them.
When I apply the Cosine Dot Product Formula I get the angles (3.64 deg for Model 1) and (2.74 deg for Model 2). The problem is I need the Outside (complementary) angles. So, I have to either add / Subtract 90 deg from the results based on the Shape/angle of the Flange. And I do not have a logic to figure this one out. Is there a way to directly get the Outside angles shown in the picture ?
3D Model Picture with Problem

A way to obtain the result can be rotate vector $B$ by $90°$ counterclockwise multiplying it by the matrix
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
which corresponds to the transformation $(a,b)\to (-b,a)$ and then applying the cosine dot product formula for vector A and the rotated vector $B$.
